# Restrict post navigation to current sub menu

Tags: posts, navigation, single

This is what I'm using to output my post navigation:

```
<?php if (is_single() ) { ?>
<nav class="post-navigation">
    <h1 class="visuallyhidden">Post Navigation</h1>
    <ul>
        <li class="prev"><?php previous_post_link('%link', '%title', 'in_same_cat'); ?></li>
        <li class="next"><?php next_post_link('%link', '%title', 'in_same_cat'); ?></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<?php } ?>
```

This will restrict the navigation to the current category (sub and parent category).

I'd like to restrict this to only the current sub category. What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Ravs mentions the third parameter in `next_post_link()`/`previous_post_link()` should be a boolean value indicating whether to restrict the link to a post in the same category. By default this is false. If set to true, it will choose the next (or previous) post which is in the same category as the current post. This includes all parent & child categories.

*The functions accept a third parameter: an array of category IDs to be excluded - but as [pointed out in the comments](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/101633/restrict-post-navigation-to-current-sub-menu/102616?noredirect=1#comment141970_102616), you cannot exclude categories to which the post belongs if you set the 'in same category' argument to true.*

So one solution is to set 'in same category' to `false`, and exclude all terms which are not associated with a post, or which are, but have a child who is also associated with a post. (This is fairly messy, you can use the [SQL filters](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/link-template.php#L1174) if you prefer)

The following returns terms that are associated with a post, and who have child terms also associated with the post:

```
/**
 * Returns a term IDs of terms that are associated with a post, and who have
 * child terms also associated with the post.
 *
 * Please note, 'parent' is a slight misnomer. If you have category structure: 
 *    Cat A > Sub-Cat B > Sub-Sub-Cat C
 * and a post belongs to A and B, but not C. 'B' is not considered a parent term
 * for this post.
 *
 * @link https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/101633/restrict-post-navigation-to-current-sub-menu/102616#102616
 * @param int $post_id. Optional, defaults to the 'current' post.
 * @return array An array of 'parent' term IDs
 */
function wpse101633_get_parent_terms( $post_id = 0 ) {

    $post_id = ( $post_id ? $post_id : get_the_ID() );
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post_id, 'category' );
    $terms_with_children = array();

    if( $terms ){
       foreach( $terms as $t ) {
            if( $t->parent && !in_array(  $t->parent, $terms_with_children ) ){
                $terms_with_children[] = $t->parent;
            }
        }
    }

    return $terms_with_children ;
}
```

#### Example usage:

**Health warning:** I don't perform any checks so you may get errors if the post has no terms etc. The following logic to get `$exclude_these` should be wrapped up in a function and moved out of the template for readability. I got lazy.

```
<?php if (is_single() ) { 

 $all_term_ids = get_terms( 'category', array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );
 $post_terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'category' );
 $post_terms = wp_list_pluck( $post_terms, 'term_id' );
 $parent_post_terms = wpse101633_get_parent_terms();
 $child_terms = array_diff( $post_terms, $parent_post_terms );

 //Exclude terms not associated with post, or that have a child who do.
 $exclude_these = array_diff( $all_term_ids, $child_terms );

 ?>
<nav class="post-navigation">
    <h1 class="visuallyhidden">Post Navigation</h1>
    <ul>
        <li class="prev"><?php previous_post_link( '%link', '%title', false, $exclude_these ); ?></li>
        <li class="next"><?php next_post_link( '%link', '%title', false, $exclude_these ); ?></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: fourth parameter in `previos_post_link` and `next_post_link` i.e. `$excluded_categories` is a string parameter while in your case you are passing `$terms_with_children` which is an array [more info](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_post_link#Parameters).and in function `wpse101633_get_parent_terms`, i think  `if` condition should be like `if(terms)` otherwise function return empty array.

Comment: @Ravs Good catch on the `if( $terms )` - I've fixed that now. R.e. the fourth parameter - my implementation is correct. The Codex is out of date. Always look at the source :).

Comment: [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_post_link) has now been updated too.

Comment: Many thanks for a detailed answer. This doesn't change the output for me I'm afraid though. Posts in other sub-categories are displaying as links - I'd like just posts in the current sub category.

Comment: i think this will not working because of this `if` condition in WordPress core [source code](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/link-template.php#L1158), in this condition `array_diff` cause of `$excluded_categories` to be empty

Comment: @Ravs, good catch, missed that. I've updated my answer. I've briefly tested this at works.

Comment: In fact, it seems I'm getting the error `Warning: array_diff(): Argument #1 is not an array in <file-path> on line 16` (which refers to your `$child_terms = array_diff( $post_terms, $parent_post_terms );`) and `Warning: array_diff(): Argument #2 is not an array in <file-path> on line 18` (which refers to your `$exclude_these = array_diff( $all_term_ids, $child_terms );`)

Comment: See my 'health warning'. You'll need to check that `$child_terms` and `$parent_post_terms` are arrays before using them in `array_diff(`).

Answer (score 0):

you code may be look like

```
<?php if (is_single() ) { ?>
<nav class="post-navigation">
    <h1 class="visuallyhidden">Post Navigation</h1>
    <ul>
        <li class="prev"><?php previous_post_link('%link', '%title', TRUE); ?></li>
        <li class="next"><?php next_post_link('%link', '%title', TRUE); ?></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<?php } ?>
```

put `TRUE` instead `in_same_cat`.

`in_same_cat` is a parameter which have value `TRUE` or `FAlSE`(default)

**Important link**:

[previous_post_link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_post_link)

Comment: This doesn't change the output for me I'm afraid. Posts in other sub-categories are displaying as links - I'd like just posts in the current sub category.

Comment: can you give me a example that helps me to understand more about your problem.